# Change mod flag color from yellow to red

Tags: feature-request, design

The mod flag (visible by mods on the top right) is easier to notice when it is red. It's currently yellow which blends in with the site's colors (especially the badges).

Could we please have the color be changed to red?

Answer (score 1):

@senseful sorry I missed this request. Do you still want the color to be changed? The reason I didn't use red is because that's what the bounty indicator color is.

Comment: No problem, I'm sure you're very busy with designing a bunch of sites. I'd prefer red, but I'll ask the other mods what they think.

Comment: I have no strong feelings against the yellow.  This is meh-ish for me.

Comment: I'm with @rchern on this one. Happy for it to be either colour - or indeed some other colour completely.